# Android: How to share video on Facebook Page using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I allow my users to record a video, then I want to share it on app Facebook page.
How do I do that?

I found [Video Upload with Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads), but it's very complicated and requires me to manage the entire video upload process. I prefer to let Facebook app to do that.

Also I found [ShareVideo.Builder](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) but is limited to 12MB, while my files can by up to 1GB.

Is there some sort of share intent that can do this job for me? Or **Video Upload with Graph API** is the only solution.

Comment: Hi, Did you got any solution to video sharing on Facebook?Please help me if you got the solution. I also want to share the video. but it is not working.